# How can I pass data using <Redirect> in react router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The situation is that I use `axios` gain data from back-end and I want to redirect from current page to another page as well as passing some data.

How can I pass data when I use `<Redirect>` to redirect?

I am using code like below, and I can't get 'profile' at the destination page. No matter, `this.props` or `this.state`

I understand that using react-router-redux is a better choice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            emailError: 'Please fill in email',
            password: '',
            passwordError: 'Please fill in password',
            redirect: false,
            profile: ''
        }

        this.handleEmail = (e) => {
            var email = e.target.value
            var emailError = ''

            if (email === null)
                emailError = 'Please fill in email'

            this.setState({
                email: email,
                emailError: emailError
            })
        }

        this.handlePassword = (e) => {
            var password = e.target.value
            var passwordError = ''

            if (password === null)
                passwordError = 'Please fill in password'

            this.setState({
                password: password,
                passwordError: passwordError
            })
        }

        this.handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            if (this.state.emailError)
                alert(this.state.emailError)
            else if (this.state.passwordError)
                alert(this.state.passwordError)
            else {
                axios.post('/user/login', {
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                }).then(response => {
                    if (response.data !== 'fail') {
                        this.setState({
                            redirect: true,
                            profile: response.data
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { redirect, profile } = this.state

        if (redirect)
            return (<Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/user/profile',
                state: { referrer: this.state.profile }
            }} />)

        return (
            <div className="content user">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <h1>Log In Your Tutor Profile</h1>
                            <form role="form" noValidate>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input id="email" type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmail} name="email" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input id="password" type="password" className="form-control" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword} name="password" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <button className="btn btn-primary submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>LOG IN YOUR PROFILE</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the whole component class.

Comment: This looks correct. How are you accessing the state in the profile component? I know accessing the state from the component you're redirecting to might require "this.location.state" or something like that. You have to look at all the props being brought in.

Comment: In route `/user/profile`, you could get the params like `this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.referrer`

Comment: The first condition is a check to ensure that location contains state since you may also directly visit the route

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally find it.

Answer (score 13):

The way you are passing your state to the `Redirect` is correct, the only place the problem should be is how you are accessing it. State can be accessed like `this.props.location.state`. However if you directly route to the `path` then state won't we available so you need to add a check

Access your state like

```
 this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.referrer
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I added [a PR](https://github.com/ekilah/react-router/pull/1) to the official React Router tutorial docs to add this information: